Solve for real $x$ that $\frac{|x-1|}{x+2} \gt 1$.
Solve
$$\frac{|x-1|}{x+2} \gt 1$$
In the case $x \ge 1$, the inequality doesn't hold.
$$\implies \frac{1-x}{x+2} \gt 1, x \lt 1$$
$$\implies 1-x \gt x+2 $$
$$\implies x \lt \frac{-1}{2}$$
So, it seems $x \in (\infty, \frac{-1}{2}) - \{-2\}$ but actual answer is $ x \in (-2, \frac{-1}{2})$.
Where did I go wrong?

For $x <-2$ the ratio is negaitve, so it cannot be greater than $1$.

You've implicitly assumed that $x+2>0$ in the step $\dfrac{1-x}{x+2} > 1 \Rightarrow 1-x > x+2$. If you considered the case $x<-2$, you'd get:
$1-x < x+2 \Rightarrow x>-1/2$, which gives no solution.

As an alternative, to avoid confusion with sign, we can proceed as follows
$$\dfrac{1-x}{x+2} > 1 \iff\dfrac{1-x}{x+2} -1>0\iff \dfrac{2x+1}{x+2} <0$$
and then studying the sign for the two factors which leads to $-2<x<-\frac12$.

Your error happens in $$\frac{1-x}{x+2}>1\implies 1-x>x+2$$ This is only true for $x+2>0\implies x>-2$ Thus you should also consider case when $x\leq -2$.
Then you will get $$1-x>x+2$$ for $-2<x<1$ and $$1-x<x+2$$ for $x\leq-2$.
Then solve the remaining.
